# Как задать кодировку для Insert в процедуре Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Сейчас при добавлении кириллицы через хранимую процедуру в таблицу ложится текст с символами вопросов. 
Кодировка на таблицу выставлена верно, если вручную добавить текст - отображается корректно.

Comment: set names, как всегда. Скорее всего там есть какая-нибудь обертка, которая позволяет вообще вызывать это методом.

Comment: Не помогло: SET NAMES UTF8; В теле процедуры после BEGIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Oleg Ponomarchuk](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk)](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk), а-а-а-а, проглядел, что это хранимка. [Тут](http://www.sunfinedata.com/tips/handling-utf8-charset-correctly-in-mysql-stored-procedure/) пишут, что нужно указывать параметры как `name TYPE CHARACTER SET utf8`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!